# mod-rewrite subdomain to subdomain dir

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a bit of a problem with rewrite rules; so what I am trying to do is this;

[name].domain.com/files/ to [name].domain.com/users/[name]/files,

where [name] is sub-domain name, for instance "nick". 
Important part is that redirection should happened, only, if request contains sub-directory; files/.

Examples I could find on Google are examples related to sub-domain to sub-directory redirection and sub-directory to other sub-directory redirection, never combination of those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting these rules in the .htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /users/%1/files/$1  [L]
```

I assumed that you didn't have a `www` in your /users/ so I added the `!^www\.` condition. If you *do* want requests for www.domain.com to go to /users/www/ then just remove that line.

Comment: Well done +1 for you... maybe `QSA` flag at the end of the `RewriteRule` (it all depends what aroma wants to do)

Comment: The query string gets appended automatically when a **?** isn't present in the rule's target. If the rule's target was `/users/%1/files/$1?redir=no` or something, it would need a `QSA`.

Comment: I know, but suppose that some other URLs which have parameters after their '?' pass through this rules: their parameters are lost. So it all depends of what aroma wants to do: either be sure to drop all the parameters before and apply only then new ones, **or** keep the old ones and mix with the new ones.